# GitHub: Read PR using bot and do operation on that content

Tags: github, pull-request

I am here with my first question. I have created one repository recently. I am also going to create android application for this.

Now everything is depends on **Pull Request (PR)** like ***If PR is valid, I have to add that data into Firebase Database.***

I have tried to find out some automation tool but did not found for this particular thing.

Can anyone help me? Is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions), which can be triggered on GitHub remote side in order to do... actions.

Example: "[Deploying to Firebase Hosting with GitHub Actions](https://natemoo.re/posts/action-firebase)" from [Nate Moore](https://natemoo.re/).
You can combine that with [actions based on pull requests](https://github.com/sdras/awesome-actions#pull-requests).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would be interested in using [Drone](https://drone.io). It's core concept of a workflow is that actions in GitHub (such as a pull request) trigger build steps (such as inserting data into a Firebase Database). It works by adding hooks to Github and is configured with a file `.drone.yml` that sits in the top level of the repository.

The drone API makes the details of the pull request available to whatever action is configured to run.